# How to get R-G-B value from color name programmatically

Tags: java, swt

By knowing the color name how can we programmatically find its red-green-blue values in Java?

Comment: What color names do you want to recognize? HTML ones? In any case the simplest thing is to build a `Map<String,Color>` to lookup them.

Comment: same as this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126029/java-color-code-convert-to-color-name

Comment: @Sajith Yes, just the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using SWT, you may be able to use the [ColorRegistry](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/resource/ColorRegistry.html) API.  There are a couple of ways to get hold of prepopulated registries (`JFaceResources.getColorRegistry()` and `ITheme.getColorRegistry()`) though it is not obvious from the javadocs what colors they are prepopulated from, and where the color definitions come from.

Alternatively use create a map and populate it with names based on the SWT.COLOR_XXX constants ans color values obtained by using `Display.getSystemColor(...)`

Answer (score 5):

The `javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet` can be used for this:

```
import javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet;

StyleSheet s = new StyleSheet();
String rgb = "black";
Color c1 = s.stringToColor(rgb);
r1 = c1.getRed();
g1 = c1.getGreen();
b1 = c1.getBlue();

System.out.println(r1 + ", " + g1 + ", " + b1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing code for the Eclipse platform then the [`ColorUtil#getColorValue`](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fthemes%2FColorUtil.html&anchor=getColorValue-java.lang.String-) method is an alternative.

It have access to all the colours for the constants that are defined in the `SWT` class, also the system colours.

The method is in the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` plug-in.

Answer (score -1):

```
Color c= Color.red;
int rgb=c.getRed()*65536+c.getGreen()*256+c.getBlue();
```

Is this what you wanted to know?

Answer (score -2):

You can get rgb value from hex value.

following code :

```
Color aColor = new Color(0xFF0096); // Use the hex number syntax
        aColor.getRGB()
```

Comment: That's not at all what the OP asked for. He wants to have RGB value if the input is, for example, `"blue"`.

Comment: yes u r right I want to get rgb value from a color name.....and I think it could be helpful by mapping only as... stated above