# How to get closest colour name from RGB value

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to get a color pixel from a image and then compare it with some other colors using switch case and display using toast but the problem is I am not able to match it using switch case. can any one help me.
here is my code

```
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
            int x = (int)event.getX();
            int y = (int)event.getY();
            int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
            switch (pixel) {
            case Color.RED:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "color", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            default:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "default", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
           }


            return false;
        }
```

Comment: > **Returns** The argb Color at the specified coordinate
It is not working because you probably do not get excatly values.

Try putting a red square image

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why the case never match is because the pixel you get is not exactly the **Color.RED**. Can you print some log to check what's the pixel really is.

The really problem should be how to get the colour name for RGB value, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20670056/2873453) is the answer you are looking for.

Below I'll show you a more straight forward but not that serious function:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();
        int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

        int distanceRed = Math.abs(Color.red(pixel) - 255) + Math.abs(Color.blue(pixel) - 0) + Math.abs(Color.green(pixel) - 0);

        if (distanceRed < RED_THESHOLD) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "RED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return false;//
    }
```

Comment: pixel:-5464781color.red: -65536 pixel.RED: 172 pixel.BLUE: 51 pixel.GREEN: 157

this is wht i get in log

Comment: Where is this pixel from? It's from a image or your draw it on the screen?

Comment: from an Image i am using in imageview

Comment: I think the image may looks like red but mathematically the value of it's not exactly red. So can you use something like if (Color.red(pixel) > 150) {Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "RED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

Comment: actually i want the user to click on colors and then a toast is shown of tht color and hence i was using switch statement for that. If i use If statement it works fine but doesnt work with switch

Comment: whts the theshold? it cant resolve it to a variable
the main problem is tht i want to compare "pixel" with the case (value).

Comment: By showing the code I just mean to give you an idea. For exactly threshold value you need to test. This solution only suitable for applications not that serious about the result. If you really need the result very accurate, then better you follow this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/20670056/2873453