# Colour name to hex

Tags: android, colors

I am retrieving football data from an API, and part of this data is the 'club colours'. The colours are arranged in a string like 'colour1 / colour2 / colour3' and so on. I am able to split this string into the separate colours with the following code

```
String[] splitClubColors = clubColors.split("/");
for(int i = 0; i < splitClubColors.length; i++) {
    splitClubColors[i] = splitClubColors[i].trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

So now I have each colour as a separate string, for instance 'red', 'white' and 'black'.

I have two separate questions:

1) is it possible to convert a colour from its name form (e.g. 'blue') to a form that is useful in Android Studio (i.e. its hex code).

2) and is it possible to set the colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent using these colours once they have been converted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to convert a colour from its name form (e.g. 'blue')
>   to a form that is useful in Android Studio (i.e. its hex code).

```
int color = getResources().getColor(getResources().getIdentifier("red", "color", getPackageName()));
```

Note: red is a color placeholder defined in `color.xml` file

> is it possible to set the colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and
>   colorAccent using these colours once they have been converted

No, you cannot although you can change the colour of some window's widgets at runtime

Reference:

[How to *really* programmatically change primary and accent color in Android Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815769/how-to-really-programmatically-change-primary-and-accent-color-in-android-loll)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

1) Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088516/convert-colour-names-to-rgb-values-in-java)

2) Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815769/how-to-really-programmatically-change-primary-and-accent-color-in-android-loll)