# Hex String to Color name

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

This is not a duplicated question, I know that were some questions asked like mine, but I need help on how I can implement to my app.

I'm trying to make a android app that can capture the colors, but i've only discoverd how I can get the Hex value, but I really need the name of the color!
please help, someone!
Below it's the whole code but where it says

```
public static String makeHexString(int value) {
return "#" + Integer.toHexString(value).substring(2);}
```

this line here, Integer.toHexString How can I make it to get the color name instead hex value?

```
 public class ColorItem implements Parcelable {

    protected final long mId;

    protected int mColor;

    protected String mName;

    protected final long mCreationTime;

    protected transient String mHexString;

    protected transient String mRgbString;

    protected transient String mHsvString;

    public ColorItem(long id, int color) {
        mId = id;
        mColor = color;
        mCreationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private ColorItem(Parcel in) {
        this.mId = in.readLong();
        this.mColor = in.readInt();
        this.mCreationTime = in.readLong();
        this.mName = in.readString();
    }

    public ColorItem(int color) {
        mId = mCreationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mColor = color;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return mColor;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        if (mColor != color) {
            mColor = color;
            mHexString = makeHexString(mColor);
            mRgbString = makeRgbString(mColor);
            mHsvString = makeHsvString(mColor);
        }
    }

    public long getCreationTime() {
        return mCreationTime;
    }

    public String getHexString() {
        if (mHexString == null) {
            mHexString = makeHexString(mColor);
        }
        return mHexString;
    }

    public String getRgbString() {
        if (mRgbString == null) {
            mRgbString = makeRgbString(mColor);
        }
        return mRgbString;
    }

    public String getHsvString() {
        if (mHsvString == null) {
            mHsvString = makeHsvString(mColor);
        }
        return mHsvString;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public static String makeHexString(int value) {
        return "#" + Integer.toHexString(value).substring(2);
    }

    public static String makeRgbString(int value) {
        return "rgb(" + Color.red(value) + ", " + Color.green(value) + ", " + Color.blue(value) + ")";
    }

    public static String makeHsvString(int value) {
        float[] hsv = new float[3];
        Color.colorToHSV(value, hsv);
        return "hsv(" + (int) hsv[0] + "°, " + (int) (hsv[1] * 100) + "%, " + (int) (hsv[2] * 100) + "%)";
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(this.mId);
        dest.writeInt(this.mColor);
        dest.writeLong(this.mCreationTime);
        dest.writeString(this.mName);
    }

    public static final Creator<ColorItem> CREATOR = new Creator<ColorItem>() {
        public ColorItem createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ColorItem(source);
        }

        public ColorItem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ColorItem[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Do you want name of the color from its hex code ?

Comment: yes please! I want to be able to show on my app the name of the color instead of an hex value or RGB

Comment: Can you clarify with an example?

Comment: so for example, my app picks the color that's in the center of the screen, but I was able to capture in RGB, HEX and HSV, but what I really want is that it shows automatically the name of the color, not in those values mentioned before. I've thought of doing, like a range of color are that certain name, but I just don't know how to apply it, help !

Comment: Are you trying to generate names for each of the more than 16 million colors that can come from a `#XXXXXX` hex string? For example, what name do you expect for `#FFFFFE`?

Comment: @Krease no I mean, this monday I'm going to present my android app, to a jury and my app needs the names of colors, how can I do that? I capture the color or the value from my camera, and it needs to be the color name

Comment: and it's there another way where can like search the web and get the name?

Comment: WHat you want isn't possible.  What color is some random hex code?  Not all colors have names, and many will have different names in different cultures.  I don't just mean languages-  I mean some cultures don't have the concept of yellow. They see it as a shade of green.  See https://www.sapiens.org/language/color-perception/  If you want to add this concept to your app, you're going to have to define what ranges of hex codes belong to what names.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yeah I totally understand, there's not names for every color, but I know that there's a way to identify the closest to a known color, but I don't how to!

Comment: @PedroGrilo There isn't, because there isn't even a universal definition of what a color is.  Its cultural, not scientific.  You would have to write any such mapping yourself.  But a decent start at an algorithm would be least difference from a set of defined colors.

Comment: @GabeSechan I need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20670056/9888243)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few color names:

```
public String getColorName(String hexColor) {
    String name = "";
    switch (hexColor.toLowerCase()) {
        case "#ff0000":
            name = "Red";
            break;
        case "#00ff00":
            name = "Green";
            break;
        case "#0000ff":
            name = "Blue";
            break;
        case "#ffffff":
            name = "White";
            break;
        case "#000000":
            name = "Black";
            break;
        default:
            name = "Unknown";
        break;
    }
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What makes this really hard is that generally we describe colours as a specific hex value. There are 2^24 different hex values but only like ~200 named colours.

What you could do is think about this geometrically using the concept of a colour cube. It has 3 dimensions, one for red, one for blue and one for green. If you also had a list of the named colours and how much R, G and B they each contain you can view those as points within the cube. Then for any colour you could find the nearest  point and that would be a good estimation of the colour. This would result in a loss of information however because before you have so many possible values (2^24) but after you only have ~200.

In order to do this you first need to parse the hex code into a a 3-d point and also parse each of your colours from your colour list into a 3-d point. For example `#ff0024` would be equal to [255, 0, 36].

Now you need to loop through your list of named colours and find the colour name with the minimum distance from your point. I'll give some pseudocode to explain this.

```
int [][] colorPoints = {{255, 255, 255}, {0, 0, 0}, ...};
String [] colorNames = {"white", "black", ...}; // These two arrays have the same length of N

int [] myColor = parseHexTo3dPoint(hexColorString); // Returns int array of length 3

double minDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
String closestColorName = colorNames[0];
for (int i = 0; i < colorNames.length; i++){
    int [] color = colorPoints[i];
    double d0 = (color[0] - myColor[0]);
    double d1 = (color[1] - myColor[1]);
    double d2 = (color[2] - myColor[2]);
    double distance = Math.sqrt(d0*d0 + d1*d1 + d2*d2);
    if (distance < minDistance){
        minDistance = distance;
        closestColorName = colorNames[i];
    }
}

return closestColorName;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try Color class method:

```
public static int parseColor (String colorString)
```

From Android documentation:

> Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB 'red', 'blue', 'green',
>   'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray',
>   'darkgray'

Eg:-

```
int myColor = Color.parseColor("#3F51B5");
myView.setBackgroundColor(myColor);
```

According to your code:

```
public static int makeHexString(int value) {
int myColor = Color.parseColor("#" + 
Integer.toHexString(value).substring(2));
return myColor;
}
```

Comment: but I want it to take a value from my camera and show a color
like this 
public static String makeHexString(int value) {
return "#" + Integer.toHexString(value).substring(2);}

it returns the Integer.toHexString(value) and I wanted a name

Comment: OP is trying to turn hex value into a string like “red”, not like you’re doing here

Comment: I have updated the answer. Do check @Pedro Grilo

Comment: You’re still converting to an int, not a String.  See the answers on the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126029/convert-rgb-values-to-color-name

Comment: @Krease how can implement cindyxiaoxiaoli code to mine?