# Figure out what the hex color is?

Tags: php, colors

If I look at the hex color code `ff0000` I know its red. If I look at `43d94e` I know its green. My question is, how do I figure out in php what color it is. According to [microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/smallbasic/2015/06/20/the-hex-colors-in-small-basic/), the main basic colors are:

```
Red
Pink
Orange
Yellow
Purple
Green
Blue
Brown
White
Grey
```

So how can I use php to figure out that `ff0000` is red? Or `5400ff` is purple. This way I will be able to group colors

Comment: do you want to consider ever hex colour? or a limited set? do you want to be able to say `ff000a` is red?

Comment: @tim Yes, consider every hex color there is. And yes, if the input is `ff000a` it should just `echo "red"`

Comment: Colour is the animals' perspective of the world, computers don't understand the concept of colour, but you can use PHP's associate array to map the value.

Comment: Convert RGB to HSV for simpler color approximation. Also, this isn't a PHP-specific question really.

Comment: There a lot of colors. https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_crayola.asp
What are you trying to accomplish overall?

Comment: @catcon but I'm sure there is a way to determine if a color is `red`? I mean, hex are just numbers? Isn't there a formula that determines it?

Comment: @blueseal Overall I am trying to group hex colors together (but not have 255 groups). Just Have 10 groups or 20 groups. Not a lot of them

Comment: Have you decided on the group of colors?  I'd square instead of taking the absolute values in the first answer for better accuracy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126029/convert-rgb-values-to-color-name

Comment: @blueseal yes. I have listed them in the first post

Comment: I wasn't sure if you have decided since you said 10 or 20, but you should be good then. Just check out the different answers in the link and see if they work.

Comment: @mario How would I convert hex to HSV?

Comment: If you refresh the page, you should see some linked resources right above your question. But if you have more questions, feel free to ask!