# How to convert rgba value into human readable text

Tags: css, selenium, automation, background-color, rgba

Need to find the button color into human-readable format below code is returning rgba value

Here is my code:

```
WebElement findbuttonColor = driver.findElement(By.id("color"));
String color = findbuttonColor.getCssValue("background-color"); 
System.out.println("Button color is :"+color);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what human-readable format mean, there are millions of colors which is possible to set for the element. Far not all of them have the names like **green**, **blue**, **red**, etc.

You get the value in rgba because the designer set up the value in rgba. The thing you could do is to define a structure that would map some well-known color codes to rgb (even not considering alpha channel) so that you could pich the "human-readable" format from that map.

Here is the example that might give a clue: [Convert RGB values to color name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126029/convert-rgb-values-to-color-name)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element color(Background color of element) by:

```
element.getCssValue("background-color");
```

You can get the element text/caption color by:

```
element.getCssValue("color");
```

For example if you want to get the background and text color of "Sign in" button for LinkedIn, the code is as follows:

```
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/");
String buttonColor = driver.findElement(By.id("searchDropdownBox")).getCssValue("background-color");
String buttonTextColor = driver.findElement(By.id("searchDropdownBox")).getCssValue("color");
System.out.println("Button color: " + buttonColor);
System.out.println("Text color " + buttonTextColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do getCssValue(), it return rgb value. You can convert it into hex by using below
backgroundColor = element.getCssValue("background-color");
        Color.fromString(backgroundColor).asHex();

this returns hex code, something like "#def3ff". You can later compare it with your availbale hexcode in yous css.

Assert.assertEquals(def3ff, ExpectedHexCode);

Note:
You can get hex code of your element by inspecting it > Styles. Refer below screenshot for details
[how to get Hexcodefrom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inyui.png) 
Thank You,