# Getting color name (from color.xml) based on color value on Android

Tags: android

I have the following `color.xml` (shortened)

```
<color name="status_orange">#ff8000</color>
<color name="status_red">#ff0000</color>
```

Now I want to get the name based on the color value, e.g. something that would return `status_red` when I pass `Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)`.

Comment: have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126029/convert-rgb-values-to-color-name?rq=1)

Comment: If I got your question correctly, what you want is probably not possible. Once the app is compiled, all those names are converted to some int values when the R file is created. Maybe you can somehow check the created constant and get the name from there, but it might need a lot of work to make it possible. Can you detail on what you want to achieve? maybe there is an easier way

Comment: I paint different segmentations on an image and want to add a legend of the colors used for the different segmentation layers without having to create another list/map that maps the segmentation layer index to the used color name. But if there is no (easy) way to make a reverse lookup of the xml file I need to add the additional map.

Comment: Using a map seems easier and cleaner to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is not possible by my knowledge and just double-checked the documentation.

Bur there is a **workaround**:

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#6200EE</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#3700B3</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#03DAC5</color>
    <array name="color_array">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

```
val expectedColor = Color.rgb(98, 0, 238)
val typedArray = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.color_array)
repeat(typedArray.length()) { index ->
    val typedValue = TypedValue()
    typedArray.getValue(index, typedValue)
    val color = typedValue.data
    Log.i("Color", "expected: $expectedColor --- result: $color")
    if (color == expectedColor) {
        val resName = resources.getResourceEntryName(typedValue.resourceId)
        Log.i("Color", resName)
    }
}
typedArray.recycle()
```

Comment: Thanks, this shows me that my approach coming from python where I could just search all members of the R.color object and compare name to value until I find my match won't work with Kotlin/Android. Really helpful! :-)